# How to loop through an object of objects?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loops, object

I'm trying to get some data from an Object that has been retrieved from [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/) using AngularJS.

The object looks like this ("feed_items" in code):

[image]

And the first 10 Objects look like:

[image]

So I'm trying to do a loop as follows:

```
function getUniqueFilters(feed_items) {    

    angular.forEach(feed_items, function(value, key){                  
        console.log(value);      
    });
}
```

The output of that console.log(value) is:

[image]

I don't understand why I'm not getting any of the first 10 Objects, which are the ones I'm needing the data from. How do I get those?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure the value of each object is not a function? Output your keys and make sure you're getting back what you want or try `value()` to see if the functions are returning the value you're looking for.

Comment: Hi @pedalpete, I've updated my post to show how the Objects look like. They are definitely not a function.

Comment: That's interesting Teknotica. This should't matter, but for consistency, I remcommend you output `function(key, value)` rather than `(value, key)`, as that is more consistent with the data structure. Having said that, have you output the content of `key` to see what that is returning? How about just passing `(i){console.log(i)` as the callback for forEach and see what that gives you. I often find these small changes will give you hints to what is happening.

Comment: Hi @pedalpete thanks for your response. I found the issue: data is still not available at that point. Thank you anyways!

Answer (score 1):

My guess is by the time you use `console.log`, the request is still not resolved.

Probably **firebase** populates the object after it gets the data from the server.

`console.log` is by reference and asynchronous so you still see the data in the console.

I'm not familiar with **firebase** but you should probably look for a callback / promise.

For testing I recommend halting the execution like so:

```
console.log(object); 

debugger; // now check inside your console
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You are right, when adding the debugger I can see the data is still not there. I'll try to get a callback then. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

what if you try to do so:

```
function getUniqueFilters(feed_items) {    

    for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
       console.log(feed_items[i]);      
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @STEVER - read below as that's what is apparently the issue.